# RegExp to match letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a regex pattern in JavaScript that accepts:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789[]`!@#$%^&*()_={}:;<>+-'
```

especially the `&` and `'`

Comment: Well, givent he [character escapes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml), maybe you can come up with a solution and we'll help you through it.

Comment: What does it mean especially? What do you want to match? What do you want to avoid matching? What is your input? Many other whats...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
[\w\[\]`!@#$%\^&*()={}:;<>+'-]*
```

Here's a [link to see it in action](http://regexr.com?2v3fe)

Comment: Shouldn't need to escape the `-` as long as it remains the last character in the class, but that's about right. -- Also, a [fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/t93C5/).

Comment: @BradChristie the link you shared doesn't have regex.